# Sign, Encrypt, and Sign Secure SOAP1.2 with C#/WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, encryption, soap, ws-security

I'm attempting to call a Secure SOAP service from C# using .NET 4.0
The SOAP service is expecting the message to be
Encrypted with certicate A,
Signed with certificate B, and then
Encrypt again with certificate A

I created a reference in Visual Studio with a local wsdl file.
I've found some articles on how to apply a UserName token, but that's not what I need. I've found ways to sign an xml document, but through the generated class there is no access to the xml.

The config file I use looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="GetStatusV01">
                <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Default" />
                <security authenticationMode="MutualCertificate" messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncryptAndEncryptSignature"
                    requireSignatureConfirmation="true">
                    <issuedTokenParameters keyType="AsymmetricKey" />
                </security>
                <httpTransport />
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://dev-server.com/GetStatusV01"
            binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="GetStatusV01"
            contract="GetStatusV01.GetStatusV01" name="GetStatusV01">
            <identity>
                <dns value="MYCRYPT" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The response I get from the server is "Invalid signature", and according a server operator, that's because there are no signatures in the xml I'm sending.

The envelope I end up sending, looks like this

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<s:Header>
<a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1" u:Id="_5"/>
<k:EncryptedHeader s:mustUnderstand="1" u:Id="_7" xmlns:k="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd">
<e:EncryptedData xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
<e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc"/>
<KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<o:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<o:Reference URI="#_2"/>
</o:SecurityTokenReference>
</KeyInfo>
<e:CipherData>
<e:CipherValue>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</e:CipherValue>
</e:CipherData>
</e:EncryptedData>
</k:EncryptedHeader>
<k:EncryptedHeader s:mustUnderstand="1" u:Id="_9" xmlns:k="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd">
<e:EncryptedData xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
<e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc"/>
<KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<o:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<o:Reference URI="#_2"/>
</o:SecurityTokenReference>
</KeyInfo>
<e:CipherData>
<e:CipherValue>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</e:CipherValue>
</e:CipherData>
</e:EncryptedData>
</k:EncryptedHeader>
<a:MessageID u:Id="_10">urn:uuid:b9c526af-36f3-423a-8d3a-19985e0db257</a:MessageID>
<a:ReplyTo u:Id="_11">
<a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
</a:ReplyTo>
<VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">uIDPo4aefT0KQzZDpNvQrzwnNtsAAAAAJzXxAWN+LESmfMegQxoSGvNvA3qZWLlOqUZ21s0IQugACQAA</VsDebuggerCausalityData>
<a:To s:mustUnderstand="1" u:Id="_12">http://dev-server.com/GetStatusV01</a:To>
<o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<u:Timestamp u:Id="uuid-6f0fe239-3cd9-4d55-b4b4-ef0e95685b22-2">
<u:Created>2015-01-23T09:20:49.574Z</u:Created>
<u:Expires>2015-01-23T09:25:49.574Z</u:Expires>
</u:Timestamp>
<e:EncryptedKey Id="uuid-6f0fe239-3cd9-4d55-b4b4-ef0e95685b22-1" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
<e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p">
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/>
</e:EncryptionMethod>
<KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<o:SecurityTokenReference>
<o:KeyIdentifier ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#ThumbprintSHA1">WvRehCqSEu079vWus36QbxPWAGc=</o:KeyIdentifier>
</o:SecurityTokenReference>
</KeyInfo>
<e:CipherData>
<e:CipherValue>ISnfyYYfr4pldTG+JkP/sKlFkM67SuMG14x8h/wGfvqHwjiqZ/qMWl3vY3SE3wa9hBjPDNl4xLw/8XB/2IlnZIUqcd1hS2CPngON3hGiu9C5GCYNPOgzAApjHhX8EO/wbjxDdNd99CFxJfM/SIQ266Z+qA2f6/o2xyoPlEwb79fm+ZBXQGQAAJOAHpojISjfykWqMA4/UyzACjhYESZsnIrc0YjTzAadBJcyBGGWVBtsRxFE3hWelN4jlKxo9BndkpDRtQBjKkk0jUJTZ9UxC+9MkybEDbS+FUBmZLc+61HR9ZNrfEqCxHZi8KsMm2QgbprYsUIuQWw7N97xe47sqw==</e:CipherValue>
</e:CipherData>
</e:EncryptedKey>
<c:DerivedKeyToken u:Id="_0" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc">
<o:SecurityTokenReference>
<o:Reference URI="#uuid-6f0fe239-3cd9-4d55-b4b4-ef0e95685b22-1"/>
</o:SecurityTokenReference>
<c:Offset>0</c:Offset>
<c:Length>24</c:Length>
<c:Nonce>Rwl/m9QIizpTsdcwLXErBQ==</c:Nonce>
</c:DerivedKeyToken>
<c:DerivedKeyToken u:Id="_2" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc">
<o:SecurityTokenReference>
<o:Reference URI="#uuid-6f0fe239-3cd9-4d55-b4b4-ef0e95685b22-1"/>
</o:SecurityTokenReference>
<c:Nonce>Jxn1Kk2F2zJ+d2+eTTS3Hw==</c:Nonce>
</c:DerivedKeyToken>
<e:ReferenceList xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
<e:DataReference URI="#_4"/>
<e:DataReference URI="#_7"/>
<e:DataReference URI="#_9"/>
<e:DataReference URI="#_13"/>
<e:DataReference URI="#_14"/>
</e:ReferenceList>
<o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="uuid-b69ebd3b-2a8b-4279-9106-d67e08facdc1-1" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3">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</o:BinarySecurityToken>
<e:EncryptedData Id="_13" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
<e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc"/>
<KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<o:SecurityTokenReference>
<o:Reference URI="#_2"/>
</o:SecurityTokenReference>
</KeyInfo>
<e:CipherData>
<e:CipherValue>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</e:CipherValue>
</e:CipherData>
</e:EncryptedData>
<e:EncryptedData Id="_14" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
<e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc"/>
<KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<o:SecurityTokenReference>
<o:Reference URI="#_2"/>
</o:SecurityTokenReference>
</KeyInfo>
<e:CipherData>
<e:CipherValue>N4TKQH9x4e2rMm+OUkXbWs0FeADT03aG1DsyP7V303vRQL/k5OS+nLmKgojOxFEn2MzZxbS4MlOeY+CxWehZaVJB0vnHA68VUTkERUtUwKuIlrNwAHwRil3icnACEtPTkgzQasz3T1f9uexZ1ZCC1x6sywdA30uTSe/qHG1MfBNYCL3UfUiWzOmrH0Nfgqoz755MvlrYeXg/YHD7JeUX2KQhai5KIHBj6UExGF1MtfVAXy3AKOGiz962M+zznc1jNMZ3LfjIyX/r16p83tadljbHT1B/UXT+3ePjmuNRqSaWgRzpCKX4hWc0C9n+RdOY9jSjW7OwttrJS8ZA+I+81rKi6FZ1B5Ivbu/4RC2/DpgxDlLMn8pkCT/4JaoVZUmeFnbonDL76qrAfk2fB2sOVe7gbeEI9g9ej0TTkW3SFHZmqMe0t0VeH//YMBwNSpNOuQbQC2sBCFdVANjxzkuiHXiYQBgB6JuxjE1m1esg6A39zK1ilQTnbp+B7sqkWHATG9EE5Cx50u1XUV3l4F6zV31u8WNYV0R+oMtZjdWH0gXLcdl8pz+hKHE2ZkuGtn5/cWqhZrXWeSX/N3tyoKwbbMgOKP9XXtneKj4bfMJJVIluVXcQbfuJLYabdA3YM+8Zqh2m8VOLQpZwlhgcSR+F9lR2mM1HHi8zZGlZPmgMv78I/QZ2UT09WXUFhJb26q5+msJuY+JKD42dKaWMwKY8Z0h6iaqdSov6dY3T1aHvfooQp0GRpHFBRAGS7aN9Vi48NzROfYt2oEKbJpc6nBQ3tvX6qOMq4JmF+etn/xnUZNF57beDU3KQd2aNDvGmcUJaFEtAiuTkbLfK0K9ehOEZw+MYgSDKJnZsrbMs0WEhOBh3WQWPIvlfa57/S8t2wUKqeevRKZ+n67/sFFcirOTCJxJOOtYVviAb5pNjPdISIcmz0sdsJGuifY73DJjlJZ/jraHtoWg+xtUyhpGjFiL/6Q5ACDSzqSeuY6XiAOkseAWEw7YaHJtbA3iSU7hjQYQzNjEGphjXBXQzDtHyts1x2INxPJVvDO+5NiCDUlYHoO+bfCvLeG0QP+Bes0wx4EOCWTBfM7WeYhwQpIo1D/c+m0IFOPmOR0wkA+l/CvwqNVzd5u/wwzKBRquBTpKFqJDfikkkvg5ZU9dE/lNs3hjKu+eGOPQacAAHNWFFqu1a7i9/bcY+4xaYkL5pK3m33jxwuahKpgZceTpyYsZxC13WBLXuoEDHD7ycKUaZ1XQzp74IaIfEYa8JN0aAG/SVeMLRG8+DlUMSTBe9xSuc2Z9ICfm8dYb8DnvO8wyAaOYwaIq0fmNLc8SJjEQVEuidLdBWznvQkwDokZgFQIPvPvRnQRfI7Jk/IAhNd/l5ZvhRIf7N7FZu8g3hjQQvqA6eEi0TE0eSQzyaJhDZnVQOBBAXnM9yjtiTh++v6SahhE9mGOGbqk9nB6Sdw6x6DqQwa2M4H6QB6W9F0a6nZMWUO4Ul8g==</e:CipherValue>
</e:CipherData>
</e:EncryptedData>
</o:Security>
</s:Header>
<s:Body u:Id="_3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<e:EncryptedData Id="_4" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
<e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc"/>
<KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<o:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<o:Reference URI="#_2"/>
</o:SecurityTokenReference>
</KeyInfo>
<e:CipherData>
<e:CipherValue>bhK3DQ/NTQSnh0pQxwhtass+Eefb1HOlrRcaXrmfUMnvwK+tjf78pmrWIXguiY7ZycI22fcnp4cJQk9af1S7L9Y5aJsv7XP8XBeAW6WggtOp/BR+OPGGS5r5qP7kr3oemSpvuapxBh5n1xAT95PSbNxyDcEt3MzMsGGvl7KK4au+bodKcWFK0GJlnxW0VotdhMTjqm7fK0qtP2xWC5RpfpQVZO1dF/4qE7/nENidFnLuszYH/7VFIatFYwhXI/UdnZ/H7E6h8MdnhLBMbuEDOFvgVx1v61YBOibIcNK6Pi9Mjm7Zh9JuOiEsdGKM/vU1o/4D4qmecu9iN+QwbFA7l2F9L10SO3dzZAyNfzjySVGU0TBy+UZTMdNW2y4TJ/l+y5TOOX++88RweL7E3EDzJg==</e:CipherValue>
</e:CipherData>
</e:EncryptedData>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I've tried fiddling about with the settings in the configuation file, but it seems I cant get it rigth.

The certifcates are set in the code

```
myClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = mySignCert;
myClient.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.DefaultCertificate = dbCryptCert;
```

-- edit:

I've tried using ProtectionLevel.

```
myClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = mySignCert;
myClient.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.DefaultCertificate = dbCryptCert;
// myClient.Endpoint.Contract.ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.Sign;
myClient.Endpoint.Contract.ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;
```

ProtectioLevel.Sign results in a NoEncryptedData(start) from the server. 
ProtectioLevel.EncryptAndSign result in a "Invalid signature", because there is no signature in the xml. I think, I what I need is actually and ProtecionLevel.SignEncryptAndSign, alas there is no such protection level.

Is there a way to configure WCF to put the signature in the envelope?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the ProtectionLevel attribute. Have a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347791%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I've tried using protection level, and I'm still looking into it, but this far, I haven't gotten it rigth yet.
I've added a little to my original question about it.

Comment: Put the [Attribute] on the class/interface of your service